# jQuery .one() with same function for different events on different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an introduction on my page which shall disappear when a key is pressed or a certain elements is clicked on. I'll use the same function for both events but as the page is heavily modified the event shall fire only once regardless which way it was triggered.

My function:

```
function start() {
    $('.intro').remove();
    $('.something-else').show();
}
```

How I bind the events:

```
$('body').keypress(start);
$('.intro').click(start);
```

If the events were the same I could say

```
$('body, .intro').one('click', start);
```

If both events were to happen to the same element I could say:

```
$('.intro').one('click keypress', start);
```

How to combine both things: having different elements and different events and the function must only be called once?

Comment: I think you can use `one()` rather than `on()` for this

Comment: The original post said one(), but Ashwin edited it to on(), which is wrong.

Comment: Ah.  I rolled it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this solution is a clean as an explicit approach, but is done using a combination of `.one()` and `.trigger()`.  Because you call `$(".intro").remove()` on one of the bound items the event handler is implicitly unbound. [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRVda/)

Excluding the html seen in fiddle, this is the code.

```
// Your event handler
function start() {
    $("#intro").remove();
    $("#main").show();
    console.log("start handler called");
}

// Handle the keypress event
$("body").one( "keypress", start );

// Allow user to click through the intro, but trigger the keypress handler on the body which is a one-time event handler)
$("#intro").one( "click", function () { $("body").trigger( "keypress" ); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to store whether your function has been called or not.

```
var started = false;
function start() {
    if(started) return;

    $('.intro').remove();
    $('.something-else').show();

    started = true;
}
```

Then your function can only be called once, every other call will be ignored.

Comment: Same applies here, too. Working with a flag variable is absolutely possible. I don't think it's quite possible but let's assume a user happens to click and press a key at the same time: Do you think that is thread-safe?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I don't think it's possible that the code is executed twice at the same time.

Comment: @dboehmer JavaScript is single threaded, events are added to a queue and executed in FIFO order. There is no way for a click event and a key press event to fire at the same time.

Comment: I would put `started = true` at the top of the `if` statement just to be safe. But, as long as nothing before `started = true` is asynchronous (i.e. `started = true` is set inside a `setTimeout`, etc.) this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use two lines of code and be done ;)

```
$('body').one('keypress', start);
$('.intro').one('click', start);
```

**Edit:**
You should manually unbind the other callback, lest it runs later, unexpectedly.

Comment: Well, of course I knew I could do that. The intention of the question was to leave the event handling up to jQuery. I find `one()` very useful and was hoping there's a way to make use of it in my case.